# 'No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: c#, .net

I am running a client application which should connect to a server side application in .NET.

Are there any restrictions on the number of connections a listening port can receive on the server?
I'm asking because I got an exception Message:

> No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 1.9.64.212:62131

Comment: Check whether the port is available?? Check firewall, antivirus etc

Comment: Yep... smells like a firewall issue.  Check to make sure port `62131` is open between you and the target machine.

Comment: Are you trying to make a single connection? That's what it sounds like, so I'm not sure why you think it's a connection limit. Windows does have a few different types of connection limits to limit virus activity, but it's unusual to run into them in the scenario you mentioned.

Comment: What do you want to know? If there is a restriction  in a random server we know nothing about, or why you can't connect to it? You should change your question and/or question title so what you *really* want to know is clear, and if you need to know of any restrictions, you need to specify what OS or software the server is using, otherwise we can only guess.

Answer (score 7):

The error "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it" means that your request got through so it is not a firewall issue. This message means that noone listens to this port. Make sure your server application is running and that it listens to the right port number (and IP address). On your server computer you can run "netstat -a -b" to find port numbers and server applications that listen to those ports.

Answer (score 3):

There are some possible reasons for that:

- The server is not running. Hence it wont listen to that port. If it's a service you may want to restart the service.
- The server is running but that port is blocked by Windows Firewall or other firewall. You can enable the program to go through firewall in the Inbound list.
- There is a security program on your PC, i.e a Internet Security or Antivirus that blocks several ports on your PC.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this message when your service throws an unhandled exception, so check that.

Answer (score 0):

This must be a firewall issue (or another connectivity issue), or the server was not started correctly.