# Host a SOAP service within a BackgroundService using .Net Core 5

Tags: wcf, .net-core

I'm new to .NET Core. I currently have a WCF host service that hosts another service that I'm trying to convert to .NET core. Using .NET 5, I created a worker service that handles the host background tasks and setup another service w/ an endpoint to handle incoming responses from another client. I'm having trouble using the EndpointAddress and ChannelFactory approach to create the endpoint and channel so the endpoint can be accessible via the outside world for response messages, but in doing so, I get the following error:

> "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (localhost:8000)"

Maybe I'm going about this in the wrong way to host the service, not sure. Does anyone know?

```
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
            return;
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseWindowsService()
                .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                {
                    services.AddHostedService<JLinkHostService>();
                });
        }
    }

    [ServiceContractAttribute]
    public interface IResponseService
        {
            [OperationContractAttribute]
            bool ResponseMessage(string sTermID, string sRespMsg);
        }
        
        
    public class ResponseService : IResponseService
    {
        public bool ResponseMessage(string sTermID, string sRespMsg)
        {
            string filePath = $"{c:\test"}\\{DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy -MM-dd_HHmmssfff")}.txt";
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filePath, $"{sTermID}\n\n{sRespMsg}");
            return true;
        }
    }

    public class HostService : BackgroundService
        {
            public override Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            {
                return base.StartAsync(cancellationToken);
            }

            public override Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            {
                return base.StopAsync(cancellationToken);
            }

            protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
            {
                ChannelFactory<IResponseService> factory = null;

                try
                {
                    Binding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
                    EndpointAddress respAddress = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:8000/response.svc");
                    factory = new ChannelFactory<IResponseService>(binding, respAddress);
                    IResponseService channel = factory.CreateChannel();
                    
                    // Test service proxy
                    channel.ResponseMessage("test", "test");

                    while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                    {
                        // Host background tasks happen here

                        await Task.Delay(Int32.Parse(GetCfgValue("AppSettings:pollingIntervalMilli")), stoppingToken);
                    }
                     }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Log.Fatal(ex.ToString());
                }
                finally
                {
                    if(factory != null)
                        factory.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Check whether the port you are using is already occupied, and change the port number if it is occupied. Or try to disable the firewall.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, it shouldn't be blocking it. I was hoping to expose a url to handle callback SOAP messages from a client, but the endpoint doesn't resolve in a browser when deployed. This is so easy in WFC, but using dotnet CORE is very difficult it appears which I need to develop around. I wished there were more examples on how to host web SOAP service within a BackgroundService, but I haven't found one.

Comment: You can try the solution to this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15247186/no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-refused-it